# Want to show each element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My i have menu options . when i click on menu options there will be a section open under the menu my html is

```
<table class="main-products">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $item_name; ?></td>
        <td>£ <?php echo $item_price; ?></td>
        <td><a class="add-cart" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="open_drop()"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="item-menu">
    <form class="item-type">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Inferno Hot" />Inferno Hot<br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Medium" />Medium<br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Jerk" />Jerk<br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Lemon & Herb" />Lemon & Herb<br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Mango & Lime" />Mango & Lime<br />
    </form>
    <div class="fright">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add-to-cart" onclick="add_to_cart('<?php echo $item_name; ?>','<?php echo $item_price ?>');">Add To cart</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript :

```
function open_drop(){
    var $this = $('.item-menu');
    $this.each('click', function(){
        if ( $('.item-manu').is(':visible') ) {
            $this.hide();
        }else{
            $this.show();
        }('hi');
    });
}
```

i want to show each menu on each elements but i failed to do that

Comment: Im assuming this gives error etc, when you say you 'failed' what does the code do now? what errors do you get in dev tools?? I've never seen 'click' events added like that, I dont think the js code is valid

Comment: event handeler is attached to html see onclick=""

Comment: you wrote .item-manu once, and .item-menu once, typo, or does it has to be like that?

Comment: if you have a inline click which calls a function which then attempts to bind more events, you'll rebind every time the menu is clicked. try and avoid inline javascript

Answer (score 0):

To add click events to you list of items, you'd need to loop it like this

```
var items = $('.item-menu input');

items.each(function (index, item) {

    $(item).on('click', function () {
        // do something
    });

});
```

EDIT: as pointed out, it's clearly too early in the morning.
The below is better, you don't need to loop unless you want to use the index and do something based on it (But even then you can just use index())

```
$('.item-menu input').on('click', function () {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: you don't really need the each if all you are doing is binding a click event

Comment: @atmd  NOw it is like this  but not working . [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/01a5f22372d35e0894a3)

Comment: Can you update your code on the question if its changed?